# Confused about Index Notation in Partial Derivative (for Batch-normalization).

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm having a little bit trouble following the indexing in this derivative.

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d\sigma_l^2}{dh_{ij}} &=& \frac{1}{N}\sum_p2\left(\delta_{ip}\delta_{jl}-\frac{1}{N}\delta_{jl}\right)\left(h_{pl}-\mu_l\right)\\
&=&\frac{2}{N}(h_{il}-\mu_l)\delta_{jl}-\frac{2}{N^2}\sum_p\delta_{jl}\left(h_{pl}-\mu_l\right)\\
&=&\frac{2}{N}(h_{il}-\mu_l)\delta_{jl}-\frac{2}{N}\delta_{jl}\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_p
h_{pl}-\mu_l\right)\\
&=& \frac{2}{N}(h_{il}-\mu_l)\delta_{jl}
\end{eqnarray}

I'll explain where I'm getting lost and what I've done below:

From the first line to the second in particular when we expand the parenthesis, what I can't follow is how we get this term:

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{2}{N}(h_{il}-\mu_l)\delta_{jl}\\
\end{eqnarray}

When I expand the first equation I get:

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{2}{N}\sum_p(h_{pl}-\mu_l)(\delta_{ip}\delta_{jl})-\frac{2}{N^2}\sum_p\delta_{jl}\left(h_{pl}-\mu_l\right)\\
\frac{2}{N}\sum_p(\delta_{ip}\delta_{jl}h_{pl}-\delta_{ip}\delta_{jl}\mu_l)-\frac{2}{N^2}\sum_p\delta_{jl}\left(h_{pl}-\mu_l\right)\\
\end{eqnarray}

Then if we sum over p wouldn't the term we would be left with be:

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{2}{N}(\delta_{i}\delta_{jl}h_{l}-\delta_{i}\delta_{jl}\mu_l)
\end{eqnarray}

I can't seem to see how we get this instead and I can't figure out the indexing and where the i is coming from:

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{2}{N}(h_{il}-\mu_l)\delta_{jl}\\
\end{eqnarray}

Thank you for your help and time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$\sum_p\delta_{ip}\delta_{jl}(h_{pl} - u_l) = \delta_{jl}h_{il} - u_l\delta_{jl}\sum_p\delta_{ip}$$
where the first term is using the canonical property of the Kronecker delta, that it "picks out" indices. When summed over a common index the delta just substitutes indices. I'm not sure what you mean by $\delta_i$.

As for the second term, the sum must be 1 because $\delta_{ip}$ is zero except for one term (when $p=i$).

Comment: Thank you. I had never heard about canonical property of the Kronecker delta but I'll read up on it now, thanks again, hopefully after reading up a bit it'll all become clear. 

What I meant with delta[i] was just in my head when I think about summing over indices I think about just how that would look in an array summation so I saw the delta[i,p] as summing over the columns of p and so those go away and we are just left with delta[i]. I have 0 formal background in mathematics so I'm just trying to figure everything out with what I think stuff means.

Comment: Ok – when I said "canonical" that may not be something that appears on Google – I sort of made it up. What I mean is that we *use* the Kronecker delta to switch indices. If we want to go from $v_i$ to $v_j$, we can just sum over a third index $k$: $v_j = \sum_k v_i \delta_{ij}$.

Comment: Wow this is very cool and useful :) haha I've been just treating it as a variable in my head for the past month, so many things make sense now. Thanks again for taking the time to answering my question,.